# How do I fix " (Variable name here) is a variable but is used like a type?"

Tags: c#, .net, redis, json-deserialization, stackexchange.redis

So I have a method that accepts an argument to provide the type, and I want to pass in this type into a deserialization of some data that I am getting back from Redis Cache. But it says "(variable name) is a variable but is used as a type". Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
protected async Task<BaseModel> GetData<T>(string id, Type modelType) {

    var data = await this.cacheDatabase.StringGetAsync(key).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<modelType>(data); // error here
    return response;

}
```

If I hardcode the model type in the deserialization, it works perfectly, but of course this is not ideal since I would like this method to handle various different model types. See below for the working code.

```
protected async Task<BaseModel> GetData<T>(string id) {

    var data = await this.cacheDatabase.StringGetAsync(key).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dog>(data); // works fine as Dog is a child class of BaseModel.
    return response;

}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `T` generic argument? Why is that not used?

Comment: I don't think this question is actually a duplicate of the one linked above. The accepted answer shows that the question had nothing to do with reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` has an overload which accepts a value of type `Type` as a second argument. So you could try this:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, modelType);
```

And there's no need for the `T` type parameter at all.

Comment: The problem is, I would need the function call to be dynamic too right? I don't know what that model used will be. It can be Dog, Cat, Goat, etc.. I have to get it dynamically from a variable. So for example, if the variable that holds the dynamic model type is named "test", then it would be GetData<test>(id). But I am sure it will have the same error saying can't use test as it is a variable and not a type. @TKharaishvili

Comment: @HackerMan33453 I've updated my answer. Hope it helps now

Comment: @HackerMan33453 I've edited my response to only contain the final answer. I think that's clearer for anyone who might come across it in the future.